# how to override private function in sales module

Tags: sales, customer-group, group

I am trying to override this following function.

```
    /**
 * Extract the form values from attributes.
 *
 * @param array $attributes
 * @param int $storeId
 * @return array
 */
private function extractValuesFromAttributes(array $attributes, int $storeId): array
{
    $formValues = $this->getFormValues();
    foreach ($attributes as $code => $attribute) {
        $defaultValue = $attribute->getDefaultValue();
        if (isset($defaultValue) && !isset($formValues[$code])) {
            $formValues[$code] = $defaultValue;
        }
        if ($code === 'group_id' && empty($defaultValue)) {
            $formValues[$code] = $this->getDefaultCustomerGroup($storeId);
        }
    }

    return $formValues;
}
```

This is the core file Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account.php

Any Help or tips
I tried preference but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Override using below method

**Step1:** app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account" /> 
</config>
```

**Step2:** app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account.php

extractValuesFromAttributes function calling from _prepareForm so override _prepareForm to override extractValuesFromAttributes function.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form;

use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

class Account extends Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form
{
    /**
     * Prepare Form and add elements to form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form $customerForm */
        $customerForm = $this->_metadataFormFactory->create('customer', 'adminhtml_checkout');

        // prepare customer attributes to show
        $attributes = [];

        // add system required attributes
        foreach ($customerForm->getSystemAttributes() as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->isRequired()) {
                $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
            }
        }

        if ($this->getQuote()->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            unset($attributes['group_id']);
        }

        // add user defined attributes
        foreach ($customerForm->getUserAttributes() as $attribute) {
            $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
        }

        $fieldset = $this->_form->addFieldset('main', []);

        $this->_addAttributesToForm($attributes, $fieldset);

        $this->_form->addFieldNameSuffix('order[account]');
        $this->_form->setValues($this->extractValuesFromAttributes($attributes));

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Extract the form values from attributes.
     *
     * @param array $attributes
     * @return array
     */
    private function extractValuesFromAttributes(array $attributes): array
    {
        $formValues = $this->getFormValues();
        foreach ($attributes as $code => $attribute) {
            $defaultValue = $attribute->getDefaultValue();
            if (isset($defaultValue) && !isset($formValues[$code])) {
                $formValues[$code] = $defaultValue;
            }
        }

        return $formValues;
    }
}
```